# Querying Ratio as a percentage

Tags: sql-server, case

I am trying to first count characters in the columns and than dividing them to create a percentage ratio column. I get errors and not sure what is causing the issue.

[Report_Graded] is boolean

[Test_Status] is text with (4) options. "Accepted, Completed, Declined, Scheduled"

```
SELECT Name, Report_Graded, Test_Status,
SUM(CASE WHEN Report_Graded= 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN Test_Status= 'Declined'OR 'Scheduled'  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) * 100 AS "Ratio_Graded"
FROM [database]
WHERE Date_Test BETWEEN '01/01/2021' AND '06/30/2021'
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY "Ratio_Graded" DESC
```

Comment: *" I get errors"* And what are those errors?

Comment: *"[Report_Graded] is boolean"* There is no boolean data type in SQL Server. Are you sure you're using SQL Server?

Comment: It's also highly recommended you do not use localised date formats. `WHERE Date_Test BETWEEN '01/01/2021' AND '06/30/2021'` will error for many because there aren't 30 months in the year. Stick to use am unambiguous format. I suggest `yyyyMMdd`.

Comment: "Column database. Report_Graded' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: What part of that error message is not clear? It tells you exactly what is wrong and how to fix it. If you are not trying to aggregate then remove the group by clause completely.

Comment: At a guess, you should be using windowed aggregates. Also don't forget that SQL Server respects data types, so an `int` divided by an `int` returns an `int`. Also, you should [edit] your question to include the error(s) you get; not put them in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHEN Test_Status= 'Declined'OR 'Scheduled'
```

is not syntactically correct. You must write
WHEN Test_Status= 'Declined'OR Test_Status= 'Scheduled'
To run the query.
Also beware of O divide. Add a COALESCE.
The query rewrited :

```
SELECT Name, 
       Report_Graded, 
       Test_Status, 
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN Report_Graded = 'Completed'
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) / COALESCE(SUM(CASE
                                  WHEN Test_Status = 'Declined'
                                       OR Test_Status = 'Scheduled'
                                     THEN 0
                                  ELSE 1
                               END) * 100 AS "Ratio_Graded"
FROM   [database]
WHERE  Date_Test BETWEEN '01/01/2021' AND '06/30/2021'
GROUP  BY Name
ORDER BY "Ratio_Graded" DESC;
```

Also date/time format can vary from the session culture. It is why it is recommended to use the ISO SQL Standard :

1. AAAAMMJJ hh:mm:ss.nnn for DATETIME (call ISO short)
2. AAAA-MM-JJ hh:mm:ss.nnn for DATETIME2, DATETIMEOFFSET (call ISO
   long)
3. AAAA-MM-JJ for DATE (call ISO long)